# Stein-Chen approximation: m balls in n boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question is due to Example 4.12.14 (p. 130) in Grimmet & Stirzaker. It reads as:

There are $m$ balls and $n$ boxes. Each ball is placed uniformly at random, different balls being placed independently of another. Let $X_r$ be the indicator function of the $r$th box being empty and let $S=\sum_{r=1}^n X_r$ be the number of empty boxes. One notice that

$$ p_r = P(X_r=1)= \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^m\tag1$$

Now, in order to use the Stein-Chen approximation (Theorem 12 in Grimmet & Stirzaker), we need to be able to define a sequence $\lbrace V_r \rbrace_{r=1}^n$ of random variables such that

$$ P(V_r=k-1)=P(S=k \vert X_r=1), \quad 1\leq k\leq n. \tag2$$

In this example, the sequence is defined as follows: $V_r = S-1$ if the $r$th box is empty. If the $r$th box is not empty, we take the balls therein and redistribute them randomly around the remaining $n-1$ boxes; we let $V_r$ be the number of these $n-1$ boxes which are empty  at the end of this further allocation. The authors now claim that the condition in (2) is satisfied.

How do you see this?